# Using Ternary Operator in Spring-Integration xpath-expression

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration and have the following two kinds of xml inputs

First XML:

`<businessArea>SomeValue</businessArea>`

Second XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<businessArea>
   <Code>SomeValue</Code>
</businessArea>
```

Now, I want to store the value of business Area in the header based on the following conditions:

1) If the businessArea has no child nodes such as `<Code>` in the second xml, then the node value of `businessArea` should be stored in the header.

2) If the `businessArea` has any child node such as `<Code>` in the second xml, then null value should be stored in the header.

I am currently using the following expression:

```
<int-xml:header name="businessArea"  xpath-expression="//businessArea"  evaluation-type="STRING_RESULT"  overwrite="true" />
```

But, the above expression will not store the null value in the header if the xml is similar to the second xml that I have shown above. 
I think I need to use ternary operator in the above expression. Can any one please suggest an expression which addresses my issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's true, the XPath doesn't such a operator, but we can overcome it with just SpEL. Thanks to Spring Integration we hava `#xpath` SpEL-function out of the box:

```
<int:header-enricher>
    <int:header name="businessArea" expression="#xpath(payload, '//Code', 'boolean') ? null : #xpath(payload, '/businessArea')/>
</int:header-enricher>
```

Comment: That's perfect.Thanks Artem.

Comment: How to add custom namespaces in #xpath expressions ?